# Why does a shadow of a fork 'dissappear' once submerged?

Tags: optics, everyday-life, refraction, shadow

NO SHADOW of the fork!

A distinct black shadow can be observed at the bottom of a glass before and after the fork enters the water, but the shadow disappears at the instant of entry, is this a phenomenon of refraction of light? (as shown in the figure)
How does it work?

[image]

Comment: On the hunt for some answers. I've been super confused for ages

Comment: Refraction. As you put the fork (or another object) in the water, the surface is not flat anymore, so refraction gets noticed.

Comment: Combined with some diffraction at the edges of the body (making the edges of the shadow blurred - can you see the shadow of an airplane flying at 5000 m altitude?)

Comment: I would remove the bold letters from the title of the question.